# Execute async method inside onLocationChanged()

Tags: java, android, json, rest, android-asynctask

I have a class which extends from `AsyncTask` and gets data in JSON format from a web service. My android app has to retrieve data asynchronously whenever the location is changed. My android activity `implements LocationListener` and I am invoking the asynchronous execution in `onLocationChanged()` method. I have tried setting zero for both minTime and minDistance parameters of `requestLocationUpdates()` method but the data which is to be retrieved asynchronously is never retrieved.

The code for my `onCreate()` and `onLocationChanged()` methods is given below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);                       

        // Hashmap for ListView
        albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    }

@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());

        new MyAsyncTask().execute();                
    }
```

The latitude and longitude variables are used in the MyAsyncTask class for getting data with respect to user's current location.

Please tell me what's wrong with my code. I have been looking for the solution since last week but haven't found any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops My Bad!

The correct code is

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

    new MyAsyncTask().execute();                
}
```

Comment: better late than never :)

Answer (score 0):

did tried debugging??
 or 
Log??
 are you getting any error???

sometimes the `location.getLatitute()` and `location.getLatitute()` returns `null` which may cause **null pointer Exception**..

that may **stopped**  reaching the `MyAsyncTask()`

check this may help you..

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       double latit =null;
       double longi =null;     
       do
       {
         latit=location.getlatitude();
         longi=location.getlongitude();
       }while(latit!=null && longi!=null);

       latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
       longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());

       new MyAsyncTask().execute();                
    }
```

The getlatitude() and getlongitude() function will return double value check this documentation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getLatitude()

Comment: Yes, Sam you're right. I am getting the null pointer exception.

Comment: What can be the reason for null pointer exception? Is there something missing?

Comment: nope.. sometimes the link will be closed before the location is received.. so you need to put a check inorder to avoid null pointer exception..

Answer (score 0):

oke, a little bit confused but let me understand it. You retrieve the data in onLocationChanged() ? example long=111 lat=222 and with your Asyntask you make a GET request to a WS with a json parameter probably long and lat and some other stuff in it ? and if you try to debugg it there are some values in logcat ? or some error ? or did you put the permision in the manifest file ? or in the phones settings ?

Comment: My web service method takes latitude and longitude as parameters and return data in JSON format. The logcat shows that a null pointer exception is being thrown.

Comment: the nullpointerexception is the easyest to handle just show us the logtrace and we try to tell where is the problem.

Comment: My log trace is uploaded at following url. The website isn't allowing me to post it here
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91190514/log.txt